# Convert date to a different date format

Tags: php

All,
I have a date format in the following output that I get from Tumblr:

2013-02-25 18:00:25 GMT

I'd like to convert this to a date format I want using the date function. I tried the following:

```
$date = date("F d, Y",$tumblr_posts->date); 
echo $date;
```

When I did this, the output was "January 01, 1970" which is obviously not right. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess `$date = date("F d, Y", strtotime($tumblr_posts->date));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) like this.

```
$date = date("F d, Y", strtotime($tumblr_posts->date));
```

To find how to parse your date use the [PHP date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) reference.